# How do i make an air native extension that calls the native alert view in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, flash, apache-flex, air-native-extension

I tried a lot of example but ended up with a crash, without any reason.
I use only windows to compile my swc and creating .ipa file. I have created a cocoa static library in Mac and do use it in creating an .ane file.

Comment: I think in the end, getting your AIR app to be polished and native-looking will be more work than just writing a Mac app.

Comment: Appreciate but, myy app works on multiple platform, so i have to do this by any means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [as3gamegears NativeAlert](http://www.as3gamegears.com/air-native-extension/nativealert/).

Comment: Was helpfull thanx a lot @Raja

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/transferring-data-ane-ios-pt1.html

Basics of the air native extension for ios
Was helpfull in my case.